# Pre-render view controller before calling pushViewController

Tags: ios

I have `AViewController` and want to push `BViewController` on to the navigation stack but `BViewController` has a lot of UI, which takes two seconds to render.

Is it possible to pre-render the UI of `BViewController` before it is pushed so that it will appear immediately?

Comment: Could you try to rephrase your question and perhaps add more information. It's not clear what you ask.

Comment: er , when push to BviewControl and bviewcontrol need to load a lot of UI .The loading UI requires at least 2 seconds. I want to know how to load comleted UI right now When push to Bviewcontrol

Comment: Is your second view controller has network call? if yes how many? is it synchronous or asynchronous?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No UI should require 2 seconds to be pushed, ever, so you indeed have a problem.

You have different solutions :

1. Push the controller **without** the data loaded, and start loading straight away, while showing a spinner. For example, if you have a tableview, it will be empty, and a spinner will spin in the middle of the screen with a little label saying "Loading...". When it's done, you populate the tableview and display it.

This way, your user knows what is going on and he can decide to go back if he wants to, or just wait the 2 seconds.

2. If it's really mandatory that the data is loaded as the user pushes, you can load it before he pushes the controller. But this really depends what kind of data it is. If it is detail view of an element, you can't load all the elements just in case. If it's a view that is always the same, you could load it when `AViewController` has finished loading, which will give you the time required to load because the user will probably stay a second or two before pushing `BViewController`. This method is probably not recommended. You could achieve that roughly like this :

   ```
    BViewController *vc = [[BViewController alloc]init]; 
   // [vc viewDidLoad];  I'm not sure this is necessary
   ```

But seriously don't go for option 2, it's most probably bad to preload the UI in many many cases. Preloading data is common, but UI, I don't think so.

3. You could reduce the amount of data you want to load. Make sure your images are compressed enough (on a small screen you don't need 4K images), make sure you're not loading a complete database when you really want a single object, etc. You should only download what the user is gonna see, not 'everything'. Again, if you've done that properly it should be already good.

I strongly suggest you try for option 3**strong text**, make sure everything is small and exactly what you need. If yes, then **go for option 1**.

Don't forget : the user knows what he wants, you don't. If he does not want to wait two seconds, he should be able to go back while it's spinning. He should NEVER be forced to wait two seconds, and your app should never be hanging.

EDIT : You said you need to load "A lot of UI". Could you show us/tell us exactly what UI takes two seconds to load? I've had pretty complex views (and I mean really complex), and UI never took that long to load.

Comment: ,Thanks  ,This is just one example。I just want to know how to reduce load bViewController time,

Answer (score 0):

Do your loading stuff in `bViewController` within background thread.

```
    - (void)viewDidLoad {
        [super viewDidLoad];

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue( DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^(void){
            //Background Thread
            // Do your loading stuff here

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
                //Run your UI Updates
            });
        });
    }
```

Comment: if I want to load UI comleted right now When push to bViewcontroller,how to  do?

Comment: Because bViewController have a lot of UI, I want to push to bViewController and bViewController UI will appear right now